# how to fetch data from one database and insert into another

Tags: php, oracle

I am working to Get data from one database connection on one server to another database connection on another server.

This is for oracle database

I fetched records from one database in an array and then process those records one by one to send to another database It was working fine for less number of records but for bulk data it consumes a lot of time

Sample Code

```
$qry = "SELECT NAME FROM EMPLOYEE" ;
$prs = oci_parse($conn1,$qry);
$exec = oci_Execute($prs);
if(!$exec)
{
    $e = oci_error($prs);
    echo json_encode($e);
    return;
}
else
{
    $hasdata = oci_fetch_all($prs,$data["EMPLOYEES"],null,null,OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);
    if($hasdata!=0)
{
        foreach($data["EMPLOYEES"] as $adata => $row)
        {
            $qry1 = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(NAME) VALUES (:NAME)";
            $prs1 = oci_parse($conn2,$qry1);                                                               
            oci_bind_by_name($prs1,":NAME",$row["NAME"]);
            $exec = oci_execute($prs1,OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
            if(!$exec)
            {
                echo json_encode($e);
                oci_rollback($conn2);
                return;
            }
            oci_free_statement($prs1);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any direct way to insert all fetched records in one go to another database.

Comment: You (or your DBA) can allow one database to access data in another database using a [database link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm#ADMIN12083). Perhaps this will help solve your problem.

Comment: I already used database Links within Oracle SQL plus I have no idea about using it in PHP please send some example I have. Confusion with which db I will open connection as in PHP and for what I use db link